# What functions we can do with PDF file in Android?

Tags: android

i just want to know what we can do with PDF file in Android??what functor PDF file in Android???

Thanks in Advance---

Answer (score 1):

> i just want to know what we can do
>   with PDF file in Android?

You can do following functions:

1. read PDF file
2. edit PDF file
3. save updated PDF file
4. delete PDF file
5. create new PDF file

Comment: Hi harry.. i am able to open and read pdf file but now how can i do with editing part.actually i get stuck here ..please gimme some idea or any other use fullink for source code..thanks

Comment: @saurabhtrivedi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219614/class-to-edit-pdf-android