# Class to edit pdf Android

Tags: java, android, pdf

I need to edit an existing pdf file in my Android app. I search on internet but i only found apps to show/edit it. I need a class to edit it from java. Where I can find it?

Comment: It is unlikely that it exists.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499960/how-to-create-pdfs-in-android-sdk

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210029/pdf-libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong with using IText ([www.itextpdf.com](http://www.itextpdf.com))?